# Docker access error when trying to run docker-compose on a local docker project

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying docker-compose up on a local docker repository in my system but do get the following:

```
ahmed@ahmed-HP-ProBook-430-G1:~/komodefi-app$ sudo docker-compose up
Pulling mm2 (komodefi/mm2:0.1)...
ERROR: The image for the service you're trying to recreate has been removed. If you continue, volume data could be lost. Consider backing up your data before continuing.

Continue with the new image? [yN]y
Pulling mm2 (komodefi/mm2:0.1)...
ERROR: pull access denied for komodefi/mm2, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

When I run docker images I do see the docker images there:

```
REPOSITORY                TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
komodefi/mm2-frontend     0.1       7a7bdda36cd5   5 days ago      1.08GB
komodefi/mm2-middleware   0.1       def632e9d4b6   5 days ago      461MB
easyengine/cron           v4.6.5    24c22a14fb21   16 months ago   19.9MB
hello-world               latest    feb5d9fea6a5   17 months ago   13.3kB
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

It's looking for "komodefi/mm2" image, which you can see does not exist in your list. Only "komodefi/mm2-frontend" and "komodefi/mm2-middleware" exist.

Answer (score -1):

The image **komodefi/mm2** with tag **0.1** that it is looking for is not available, as you can see in the list below.

You may update the docker-compose.yaml file or if you pulled the image before deletion, and it is available on your local machine you can run the following command

```
sudo docker-compose up --force-recreate
```

this will create the container even if the image has been removed.

If this works, you can make an image from the container if it works properly with the following command.

```
docker commit my-container komodefi/mm2
```

then you can push it to your docker repo.

If none of the mentioned ways did not work, you may review your docker-compose.yaml file and make sure that each container exists.